# Building a BST from a list in depth-first postorder without reversing the list

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

The easiest way to reconstruct a BST from a list of elements in depth-first postorder is to first reverse the list and then build the tree using a slight modification of the algorithm for building one from preorder. Unfortunately, if the list is really a (finite) stream, then the memory requirements for doing this may be prohibitive and efficiency will certainly go out the window. It would be interesting, therefore, to find a more incremental way to do it.

The trouble, of course, is that looking at the first few elements of a postorder traversal will not necessarily tell you very much about the shape of the tree. If you see [2,1,...], then you know that you have a subtree with root 1 and right leaf 2, but if you see 1,2 then you can conclude very little. One thought I had was that maybe a nondeterministic parsing technique could do the trick, but I can't quite wrap my head around that properly, or see a way to avoid bad cases.

Note: If answers include code, it would be nice if said code were in Haskell, Scheme, or perhaps SML.

Comment: Is the stream already in any particular order, or is the order of elements random?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The stream is in depth-first postorder. I think my last edit clarifies the question.

Comment: Actually, if you use a self-balancing tree, I don't think the input order matters at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the goal is to get back the original tree. That is, given a function f that takes a binary search tree and produces a list of its nodes in depth-first postorder, we want to produce a function g such that g . f = id.

Comment: Is there a reason that the nodes were written out in the wrong order, or is that just an oversight?  Can the original problem be corrected?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm just trying to come up with a sort of "bonus challenge" for a classic exercise. Doing it in O(n) time is the first challenge; trying to do it with less than O(n) additional space would be the final one. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting problem.  I don't think you have to load the whole tree all at once into memory, just enough to identify the root of each subtree.

Comment: You can't (deterministic, I think) without read tail values (roots). Preorder is (in stream) as `"Left, Right, root"` when `Left < root < Right`, then, `Left < Right`. If you unknown `root`, how differenciate `"A, B, r"` (with `"A < x < B < y"`)? if `r == x` you get a tree, if `r == y` other. Is a great problem to think about space consumption :) . In a probabilistic way...

Comment: @josejuan, I agree with you, but I just don't see how to *prove* it.

Comment: @dfeuer, I have given you a counterexample, you must skip ALL stream to complete that tree (and you can't predict branch splitting). This is not a proof (of course) but you can't do it in O(n) (I think, of course).

Comment: Let `xs=[0,2,3,4,5,...,n,r]`, if `r==1` then `[2..n]` branch are linked at right (`2->3->4->...`), if `r>n` then all nodes are linked at left (`0<-2<-3<-...`). Then you should be able change direction and split branches with `O(1)` cost (to get a total cost `O(n)`). This really doesn't look good. The best algorithm you can use is `O(n log n)` and space `O(2n)` (or read from end of stream and so on). Of course you can write code to use `O(n)` space, modifying tree (but resultant code is much complex than the trivial one).